# Login app with existing user - phone Auth Firebase Android -

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

I'm developing an app where I use the firebase phone auth method. It works great with first time users, they get the sms code and get registered in the firebase console. But if they signout or reinstall the app, they can't access to the app menu since they are already in the firebase console database.

I don't know how to tell the app if the user is already registered, then make an intent to the main activity, if it's not registered, then go to the signup activity. I know how to get the current user but I don't know how to skip the verification step if the user exists in the firebase database.

Hope you can get me.

Here's my code.

````
    private static final String KEY = "userAuth";
    private static final String TAG = "PhoneAuthActivity";
    private static final String KEY_VERIFY_IN_PROGRESS = "key_verify_in_progress";

    // [START declare_auth]
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    // [END declare_auth]

    private boolean mVerificationInProgress = false;
    private String mVerificationId;
    private PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken mResendToken;
    private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks;

    // Instance of Firebase
    private PhoneAuthProvider phoneAuthProvider;

    private String verificationId;
    // id user from DB
    private String idUser;

    private EditText activationCode;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_verify_code);

        // Restore instance state
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        }

        // [START initialize_auth]
        // Initialize Firebase Auth
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        // [END initialize_auth]

        // Initialize phone auth callbacks
        // [START phone_auth_callbacks]
        mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

            @Override
            public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
                // This callback will be invoked in two situations:
                // 1 - Instant verification. In some cases the phone number can be instantly
                //     verified without needing to send or enter a verification code.
                // 2 - Auto-retrieval. On some devices Google Play services can automatically
                //     detect the incoming verification SMS and perform verification without
                //     user action.
                Log.d(TAG, "onVerificationCompleted:" + credential);
                // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
                mVerificationInProgress = false;
                // [END_EXCLUDE]

                signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
            }

            @Override
            public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
                // This callback is invoked in an invalid request for verification is made,
                // for instance if the the phone number format is not valid.
                Log.w(TAG, "onVerificationFailed", e);
                // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
                mVerificationInProgress = false;
                // [END_EXCLUDE]

                if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {

                } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                    // The SMS quota for the project has been exceeded
                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Quota exceeded.",
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String verificationId,
                                   @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
                // The SMS verification code has been sent to the provided phone number, we
                // now need to ask the user to enter the code and then construct a credential
                // by combining the code with a verification ID.
                Log.d(TAG, "onCodeSent:" + verificationId);

                // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
                mVerificationId = verificationId;
                mResendToken = token;
            }
        };
        // [END phone_auth_callbacks]

        activationCode = findViewById(R.id.eTextActivCode);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        String phone = getIntent().getStringExtra("phone");
        idUser = getIntent().getStringExtra("user");
        sendVerificationCode(phone);
    }

    // [START on_start_check_user]
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(currentUser != null){
            Intent intent = new Intent(VerifyCodeActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            intent.putExtra("user", idUser);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        if (mVerificationInProgress) {
            startPhoneNumberVerification(getIntent().getStringExtra("phone"));
        }
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
    }
    // [END on_start_check_user]

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean(KEY_VERIFY_IN_PROGRESS, mVerificationInProgress);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        mVerificationInProgress = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_VERIFY_IN_PROGRESS);
    }

    private void startPhoneNumberVerification(String phoneNumber) {
        // [START start_phone_auth]
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
                60,                 // Timeout duration
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
                this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
                mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
        // [END start_phone_auth]

        mVerificationInProgress = true;
    }

    private void verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(String verificationId, String code) {
        // [START verify_with_code]
        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, code);
        // [END verify_with_code]
        signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
    }

    // [START resend_verification]
    private void resendVerificationCode(String phoneNumber,
                                        PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
                60,                 // Timeout duration
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
                this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
                mCallbacks,         // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
                token);             // ForceResendingToken from callbacks
    }
    // [END resend_verification]

    // [START sign_in_with_phone]
    private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful() || activationCode.equals("123456")) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(VerifyCodeActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                intent.putExtra("user", idUser);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(VerifyCodeActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        } else {
                            // Sign in failed, display a message and update the UI
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                                // The verification code entered was invalid
                                // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
                                activationCode.setError("Ingresa un código válido.");
                                // [END_EXCLUDE]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
    // [END sign_in_with_phone]


    public void verifyPhoneNumber(View view) {
        String code = activationCode.getText().toString();

        if (code.isEmpty() || code.length() < 6) {
            activationCode.setError("Ingresa un código correcto");
            activationCode.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(mVerificationId, code);
    }

    public void resendActivationCode(View view){
        resendVerificationCode(getIntent().getStringExtra("phone"), mResendToken);
    }

    private void sendVerificationCode(String number) {
        // Initialize Firebase Auth
        phoneAuthProvider = PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance();

        phoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(number, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD, mCallback);
    }

    private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallback = new
            PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

                @Override
                public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken
                        forceResendingToken) {
                    super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
                    verificationId = s;
                }

                @Override
                public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                    String code = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();

                    if (code != null) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        //verifyCode(code);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(VerifyCodeActivity.this,
                            "Error al verificar el número de teléfono: " + e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            };
} ```
````

Comment: do you use add() or set() to enter user info in firebase database?

Comment: No, I'm not using a firebase database, I'm only using the firebase console to see the users registered using the phone auth method in my app

Comment: then just set a checkpoint like null checker before auth. if (firebaseUser != null) {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Dependent** on your question and comments your need to know if user is already login before or is it first time and you not have server database to save user data

But i will give you two answer for if you use another server database

> **NOTE** :  in your question  your are write you want user in second time when login is go to menu activity without verification but in
>   rely is can't happen because like this anyone can use any phone number
>   and login, so verification code with phone is like password with email
>   to make sure the authentication is successful

1.First Solution :  If you have another database server 
in **first time** user login you will save **user data** like name and phone,location,uid...etc in your database, so you can bind user bwtween firebase phone auth with database by **uid** or **phone**, now when user login by firebase in second time you will check by uid or phone if user is already in your database(is not first time) or not(is first time for user).

2. Second Solution : use [AdditionalUserInfo](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AdditionalUserInfo) to check if user is newUser or is login before after try to `signInWithCredential` inside `onComplete`

like this

```
OnCompleteListener<AuthResult> completeListener = new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                boolean isNew = task.getResult().getAdditionalUserInfo().isNewUser();
                Log.d("MyTAG", "onComplete: " + (isNew ? "new user" : "old user"));
            }
        }
    };
```

I hope this help you

Answer (score 2):

I find it the easiest way to use Firebase Authentication; than you could use something like this;

```
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
```

```
if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) 
{
// go to home activity 
}
if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() = null
{
//go to login activity
}
```

However you than need to take care that you are also signing out the user in FirebaseAuth.
Like this;

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```

Hopes that helps!